# What is the best explanation to say these vectors are linearly dependent?

Tags: linear-algebra

(2.7,18,28),(57,7.2,15),(3.14,159,2.6),(161,803,3.9) < 4vectors.Justify whether they are linearly indepedent or dependent.

My idea is linearly dependent because each vector cannot be expressed as a linear combinations of other vectors. In my opinion, this is true because of all those decimal.
I would like to hear from you all. Thank you!

Comment: There are four vectors, and they are three-dimensional. That should settle it right there.

Comment: ohya! so no of variables>no.of equations>>so in row echelon form,matrix will have free column. thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You have got 4 vectors of dimension 3 each . For three dimensional space we need 3 vectors atmost to get spanned by . So you have 1 extra vector which must be due to combination of other vectors .

Answer (score -2):

No, that doesn't work.

On the other hand, observe that you have **four** vectors of dimension **three** and $4>3$...